# Spam flag related to Intel FORTRAN compiler is disputed

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

Why is this answer

> [image]

not considered a spam? The question is old and has nothing to do with this commercial software

> [image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wasn't the moderator who handled this flag but I'd have done the same too. I don't believe there's any evidence that the user who posted that answer is affiliated with Intel's Fortran team and using that answer to promote it.

There might be problems with that answer, but promotion isn't one of them.

---

In the more general case though spam usually has a bunch of "tells" that give it a certain smell. You'd be surprised how much spammers (even astroturfers) give away as solid evidence:

- linkedin profiles
- whois records
- the company's own "about us" page
- other forum postings
- old deleted spam posts on the same question with the same link

often give the game away without needing a diamond to see it.

Spam has a pretty distinctive smell usually too:

- new users who only signed up to drop it
- previously unknown blogs with dates of today/yesterday
- distinctive phrasing that usually over emphasizes how amazing/good value the product is without actually containing any information.
- Except for fraudulent voting (which has its own give away signs) spammers don't usually get much rep. It's pretty rare for someone with much more than 100 rep to go rogue and start astroturfing.
- Other similar low rep users posting similarly dubious answers (use advanced searching to find this)
- Affiliate codes in links (or motive more generally)
- URL shorteners (can be a sign of a blacklisted URL or hidden affiliate codes)

If you dig around on something that's not a clear cut case flag "Hey, this smells pretty spammy because X" - I'll usually validate as helpful, even if I didn't agree in the end because of private info. Even a declined spam flag isn't something to get worked up about though, it's the only way we have of saying "Hey, I looked into this and on balance I don't agree". If it looks fishy dig a little, report what you find and don't take it personally if we disagree when we look at it with a little extra info.

The end decision is almost always based on diamond or at least 10k information though.

Comment: The problem with the answer is it doesn't answer the question not even close. But then you woouldn't flag it for that reason alone, just down-vote and it will be closed eventually.

Comment: I would sincerely hope that Intel's Fortran compiler team would do a better job of answering the question... with at least proper grammar.

Comment: @Lankymart No, NAA and VLQ flags (essentially the same thing) apply.

Comment: @bjb568 Well not an answer is "subjective" as everything is, but if flagging for "spam" is disputed then "not an answer" doesn't stand a chance.

Comment: @Chris Evidence of affiliation does occur sometimes. Sometimes via mention in the user profile (in the link or About Me), sometimes by the presence of phrasing like "we" or "our".

Comment: @Lankymart Spam is just a more extreme version of the "only a link" use case for NAA. Yeah, some NAAs are somehow declined for no reason, but that doesn't mean that it's worse than the spam flag.

Comment: @Lankymart: A spam flag is a huge black mark against the poster, while NAA flag mostly affects the post and has little impact on the user.  So people are **very** careful about spam flags.

Comment: @Chris No, I don't think there are any objective criteria. I had a spam flag disputed where a post linked directly to a commercial service. On the other hand, I've seen posts deleted as spam where somebody posted links to some plugin, without any indication that they were associated with it. Based on my observation, I think it's more a question of frequency than a question of content. For the post in question, it looks like the link was only posted once.

Answer (score 7):

Considering that the last question of the OP was "What is FORTRAN 14?", I'd even say that the flagged post does in fact answer the question partly.

I don't say that it is a complete or good answer, but IMHO it was a honest attempt to help by answering a question.

Comment: I disagree. This is clearly nothing else than a _link-only_ answer. Links do not answer questions, that's the rule on SO.

Comment: @MathiasMüller how is that answer "link only"? There is text before the link, it is indeed not "link **only**" by definition.

Comment: Sure, but the text does not have any explanatory value. Are you claiming that "Intel have released a FORTRAN compiler version 14" is a valid answer to the question "What is FORTRAN 14?"?

Comment: @MathiasMüller Where exactly did I state that I considered it being a **valid** answer? "Pizza" can be used as answer to the Question "Hey man, how is it going?" without being a *good* or even **valid** answer. It is still an answer though.

Comment: Modulo wording, a fair interpretation of the answer could be "maybe they are referring to version 14 of Intel's FORTRAN compiler"?  Should perhaps be a comment instead of an answer, but again, I agree that it's probably an honest attempt at answering the question.